# Excel - Use Overlapping Date Groups in Pivot Table (WTD, MTD, YTD, etc.)

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched all over stack overflow and elsewhere to find the answer to this, but have had no success. Imagine I have a bunch of data, each with an individual date, and I create a pivot table. To compare chunks of time (Week X vs Week Y), I can create two groups of those dates, put Date into columns section of builder, and all is well. It will have Date (grouped by Week X, Week Y, then totals) with all metrics related to each.

However, lets say that I want to calculate totals that have overlaps; to simplify matters, let's say I want "to-date" metrics, like week-to-date, month-to-date, quarter-to-date, year-to-date, etc. This means that yesterday's date falls into all of those categories, and natural grouping won't allow overlaps like this.

The closest solution I read - from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178641/excel-pivot-table-overlapping-date-ranges) -  is to create multiple pivot tables.  In this scenario, I could create a pivot table per grouping of date (one for WTD; one for MTD; etc.). If there were only a few rows, in a standard order, putting these pivots next to one-another and hiding the duplicated "first column" might work. The issue here in my implementation is due to sorting; I need to sort rows by one of the metrics, and this metric / its resulting row order will change from timeframe to timeframe.  so there would be no easy way to eyeball a row and see groups of metrics for each timeframe directly to the right of it.

Is this at all do-able? / Does the way I am describing the issue make sense? As I was writing this, I realized that "totals" / sub-totals don't make sense when thinking about groupings like this, since it would have duplicate data in these totals... perhaps there's a better way to approach this issue I haven't thought of. Not a VBA pro, but happy to use that if you have a work-around that utilizes it. Any input appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? If you have an SQL backend the I'd suggest that you prep your data before loading it into Excel. Pivot tables doesn't really seem like the best idea because any data value in a pivot table has only **one** place to go (allowing for drill-down functionality). If you want something to show multiple times (overlapping) then this data would have to be multiplied in the source data. So, I'd go away from a pivot table and make my own custom report. As I said, SQL would be great: fast and easy. VBA would be cumbersome and bulky (compared to SQL).

Comment: @Ralph - thanks for your follow-up! It is a SQL query that is pulling the data, however I am having difficulty trying to wrap my head around how this would work. Basically, the row-level data from the query already has time-frame grouped metrics - like 7 day vs. 15 day revenue - that occurred within 7 days or 15days of the origin date of this row. The point of the pivot table is to calculate metrics  (like 7 or 15 day revenue), based on aggregate groupings of origin dates. I don't think there's a logical way to double group the data SQL-side, especially since the pivots are dynamically grouped